# compilation error in code

Tags: c++

I have written the following program and it has some compilation errors

ERRORS:

> 1. prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> 2. prog.cpp:13: error: name lookup of 'i' changed for new ISO 'for' scoping
> 3. prog.cpp:9: error:   using obsolete binding at 'i'

AND MY PROGRRAM IS ON SORTING AN ARRAY IN ASSENDING ORDER:

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  

int main()  
{  
    int temp,t,a[10];  
    cin>>t;  
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)  
    {  
        cin>>a[i];  
    }  
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)  
    {  
        int j=i+1;  
        for( ;j<t;j++)  
        {  
            if(a[i]>a[j])  
            {  
                temp=a[i];  
                a[i]=a[j];  
                a[j]=temp;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)  
    {  
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: This question is obviously about C++, but you tagged it [c#]. Please pay more attention.

Comment: you are missing an `int` before the `i` in your second and third `for` loop

Comment: If you normalize the CAPS sentence I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `i` inside of the `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
```

Therefore, `i`'s scope is limited to that `for` loop. `i` does not exist outside of that `for` loop.

So, when you try to reuse that `i` in the next `for` loop

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
```

you get an error. You have to declare `i` again:

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
```

Same thing in your last `for` loop. It would also be very helpful if you indented your code correctly.

---

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  

int main()  
{  
    int temp,t,a[10];  
    cin>>t;  
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)  
    {  
        cin>>a[i];  
    }  
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)  
    {  
        int j=i+1;  
        for( ;j<t;j++)  
        {  
            if(a[i]>a[j])  
            {  
                temp=a[i];  
                a[i]=a[j];  
                a[j]=temp;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)  
    {  
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only declare the variable i in the first for-loop. The declaration of the variable is only local for that loop, which means that the i will not exists outside the loop.

Instead of:

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
```

Try

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your 'i' variables.

Nowadays variables declared in a 'for' statement are only useable in the 'for' block, not outside the 'for' block.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to declare all your variables  in the begining. So this way the variables are declared as a local integer and cannot be used outside the `for loop`. I tried declaring them outside the function `int main()` and it worked
The right code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i = 0;
int a[10];
int temp = a[i];
int t;
int main()
{

    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int j=i+1;
        for( ;j<t;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are declaring `i` inside the function scope.
You can decide if you want to declare the variable i once at the main, or each time as a local scope variable inside a the `for` scope.

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  

int main()  
{  
    int temp, t, a[10];  
    cin >> t;  

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<t ; i++)  
    {    
        cin >> a[i];  
    }  

    for(i=0; i<t; i++)  
    {  

        for(int j=i+1; j<t; j++)  
        {  
             if (a[i]>a[j])  
             {  
                 temp=a[i];  
                 a[i]=a[j];  
                 a[j]=temp;  
             }  
        }  
    }  

    for(i=0; i<t; i++)  
    {  
         cout << a[i] << endl;  
    } 

    return 0;  
}
```